# PersistenceContext in CMT seems to be different of PersistenceContext in BMT

Tags: java, transactions, ejb-3.0

I'm currently having issues refreshing the data in my PersistenceContext.
I have a CMT EJB3 bean which calls a BMT EJB3 bean. In the BMT bean, I do some process logic on an object. I commit the changes and I can see the changes in the database.

After the process finishes in my BMT method, I return to my CMT bean. I refetch (.find() method) my object from the PersistenceContext (because the BMT bean changed some values), but I'm still getting the old values of my object. I even tried the .refresh() method, but the data doesn't get updated.

Is it possible the CMT and BMT beans are using a different PersistenceContext?

Comment: Have you tried with `getReference(entityClass, pk)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The persistence context propagates via a running transaction, and in addition to that for a normal persistence context (e.g. non-extended) the life-time of its L1 cache is scoped to the same transaction.

So if you start a new transaction in your BMT bean, interact with its persistence context and then commit, then indeed the calling CMT bean will not have the updated values in its persistence context.

Reading the values fresh from the DB should work though. So if you see those changes in the DB and especially if both the CMT and BMT beans are deployed in the same application (thus no L2 inconsistency effects), then `refresh` actually should work.

What happens in a new call to the CMT bean? Does it see the updated values then?

Comment: Hi Arjan. After a new call to the CMT bean, the values are updated yes! But I want them to be updated in the first call.

To understand the whole issue. I have an object Document which has a Set of objects of the type "Field".

So after calling the BMT bean, I do:

for (Field f : document.getFields() ) {
   Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery("Select f From Field where f.document = :document");
   Field f = (Field)query.getSingleResult();
   getEntityManager().refresh(f);
}